# Multi-Type search in elasticsearch with distinct ID's after ordering

Tags: elasticsearch, distinct

I have elastic index with types for different languages.

I need to select distinct documents with current language if available and any single other if current language is not available.

I can do something like this in PostgreSQL (although there's probably a better way to do this):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (i) * FROM
(SELECT * FROM
(SELECT id i, name n, locale l, f_active a FROM news c
UNION ALL
SELECT id i, name n, locale l, (SELECT cc.f_active FROM news cc WHERE cc.id = cl.id) a FROM news_locale cl
) s
ORDER BY l = 'en' DESC
) ss
WHERE a = true
```

I wonder, if it's possible to do so in elasticsearch?

P.S. I could've stored all localed fields in one document, but the problem is that most of the time I need to select only one particular locale.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to achieve something like this:

```
{
        "query": {
            "query_string": {
                "query": "(isActive:true) AND (isDeleted:false)"
            }
        },
        "aggs": {
            "top_ids": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "id",
                    "order": {
                        "title": "desc"
                    },
                    "size": 10
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "top_ids_hits": {
                        "top_hits": {
                            "sort": {
                                "_script": {
                                    "type": "number",
                                    "script": {
                                        "inline": "doc['locale'].value == lang ? 1 : 0",
                                        "params": {
                                            "lang": "ru"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "order": "desc"
                                },
                                "_score": {
                                    "order": "desc"
                                }
                            },
                            "size": 1
                        }
                    },
                    "title": {
                        "max": {
                            "field": "num_field"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "size": 0
    }
```

But there are two problems: I cannot set from for top_ids terms and cannot sort by non-numeric fields.

I guess for now there's no solution for these problems.